# Updating Gradle docker plugin failing with latest version 6.7.0

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle

How to fix this error while updating gradle docker plugin:
Error:
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: parentFile for class: org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$DefaultRegularFileVar

Gradle: 7.5
Java: 1.8
application: spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
createDockerfile.destFile.parentFile
```

You should use

```
createDockerfile.getDestDir()
```